# View artifacts leaking into the model of MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, design-patterns

In an ASP.NET MVC application (which has very little chance of having its view technology ported to something non-HTML, but whose functional requirements evolve weekly,) how much HTML should ideally be allowed to be directly represented in the Model?

I might come across as a design bigot for this, but I regard it as bad practice to allow any view constructs to "leak" into the model in an MVC application (and vice versa). For example, a Model that represents an item you're about to purchase should know nothing about the HTML check box that says "add giftwrap/message", nor should it know about any HTML drop down lists for payment card types. Conversely the View shouldn't be doing work like figuring out button text by translating keys into values (by looking in resource files.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None at all, unless the model object is something like a blog post or item description that itself can contain HTML, and even then it's probably better to use a markup language designed for the purpose... there's plenty of libraries for those.